# Plink command is invalid to cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to throw a plink command to my esx server and grep the linux output of the command. The code above does not work. But if I remove the | grep part it works again. Is there any other way to achieve the same results but making the command passable with cmd.exe?

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=1 DELIMS=:" %%A IN ('TYPE %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Users\Ian\Desktop\backup.list') DO ECHO %%A & (FOR /F "TOKENS=2*" %%B IN ('%PLINK% -batch -ssh %USERNAME%@%ESXHOST% -pw %PASSWORD% vim-cmd vmsvc/get.datastores %%A | grep datastore') DO ECHO %%B)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at it (without plink.exe to test with at the moment), the problem seems to be that the `|` is being interpreted by cmd.exe instead of being passed as part of the argument string to plink.exe.

If that guess is correct, it's an easy fix: just escape the `|` by putting a `^` in front of it, so that `%%A | grep` becomes `%%A ^| grep`.

Comment: Wow this was posted a while ago, I almost forgot about this. I moved on to perl, batch just didn't have it. Still thanks for the input.